# Firebase Cloud Messaging not working when downloaded from appstore

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My firebase cloud messaging works when i install my app directly from xcode to my iPhone with live urls and all. But its not working when i upload the same code on Appstore and thereafter download it from there. It says "invalid registration". Any help would be highly appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Show your configuration for firebase push.

Comment: Did you configure both Development and Production Certificates for Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) 
{
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox)
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Prod)
}
```

> FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox used when we download it from TestFlight or when we are testing in development mode and FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Prod used when we release production build or when we download from AppStore

Comment: When i do  this:-  FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Prod)  it is not working on both via appstore and system. Do i need to do anything extra in the console of firebase for production build. As in my xcode i checked automatically manage sign in.  And on the firebase console Auth key is uploaded.

Comment: @RohitJha it seems like you didn't configure production certificates for firebase kindly check your configurations of firebase

Comment: I uploaded Auth Key in firebase console. Could you please tell me how can i configure production certificates for firebase. Because in the console panel of firebase there is no such production and development as such. Thanks

Comment: @RohitJha can you please refer this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs this is google firebase doc and if you find my answer correct please mark it as correct .